# hot-module-loader apply cold to node_module package

Tags: reactjs, webpack, kendo-ui, react-hot-loader

I'm trying to figure out how I can apply cold() to just a single node package.

according to the docs I need to use setConfig and also apply another babel-loader to include just node_modules. However I can't for the life of me figure out where or how to implement this.

```js
import { setConfig, cold } from 'react-hot-loader'
setConfig({
  onComponentRegister: (type, name, file) =>
    file.indexOf('node_modules') > 0 && cold(type),
})
```

I'm using Kendo UI React which does not support HMR. So I need to wrap the PanelBarItem so that react-hot-loader doesnt wrap the component. What I would like to do is apply this rule all my kendo packages so I don't have to explicitly call cold on each component when I use it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import messages from './messages';
import { Button } from '@progress/kendo-react-buttons';
import { PanelBar, PanelBarItem } from '@progress/kendo-react-layout';
import { changeLocale } from '../LanguageProvider/actions';
import { cold } from 'react-hot-loader';

class Home extends React.Component {
   render() {
      cold(PanelBarItem);
      return (
         <div>
            <PanelBar title="Test">
               <PanelBarItem title={'Sales Forecasts'}>
                  <PanelBarItem title={'Q1 sdfds'} />
                  <PanelBarItem title={'Q2 Forecast'} />
                  <PanelBarItem title={'Q3 Forecast'} />
                  <PanelBarItem title={'Q4 Forecast'} />
               </PanelBarItem>
            </PanelBar>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your webpack, you probably have something like this:

```js
{
    module: {
      rules: [{
        // testing for js/jsx files, and using babel-loader load them int webpack
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        
        // Maybe looking only on your source folder
        // (and looking aside from the node_modules as a consequence)
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        ],
        
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader', // Ask babel to eat up those files and prep them for webpack
          options: {
            presets: [
              // What ever babel presets you might use
            ],
            plugins: [
              // Some babel plugins you might use, like transform-runtime, or lodash
              
              // This plugin is RHL's dude that goes over your code and marks
              // things for patching later by the client
              'react-hot-loader/babel',
            ]
          },
      }, {
        // some other loaders for styles, images etc.
      },]
    }

    // More webpack stuff
  }
```

Usually, you would not apply the "js/jsx" loader to `node_modules` (as shown above) and this is why the babel plugin which RHL uses to patch things up never gets a chance to process the Kendo code.

What the documentation asks you to do it to add another loader that looks for js/jsx files but only applies the RHL babel plugin. like this:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [{
      // Your usual loaders including the usual babel-loader for your code
    }, {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: [
        // Focus on the folder of the module you want to "cold" later
        // or go for all node_modules if you need to
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/<YOUR MODULE>'),
      ],
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: [
            // The only plugin
            'react-hot-loader/babel',
          ]
        },
    }]
  }
}
```

Then, when you configure RHL on the client (first thing you do) by calling `setConfig` you will also get the files from the now marked modules to apply `cold` on.

On your very very first file, just like they show in the documentation, require the `rhlconfig.js` file. The `onComponentRegister` should now also see files from `node_modules`.